# Queries run really slow on sparkSQL

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I am currently working on 7 Nodes cluster with 16 cores each and using 128 GB memory.

My configuration looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpZ8C.png)

Some of my queries with joins run really slow and i am dealing with data with millions of rows..

Edit:
Queries includes joins.. 
Selecy a, b, c from 
(SELECT MAX(data_mo_dt) AS MAX_DATE FROM M_FRMLRY_PLAN_DRUG_RSTRCTN_TEMP) B
inner join
M_FRMLRY_PLAN_DRUG_RSTRCTN_TEMP A
on 1=1
WHERE  a.data_mo_dt >= Add_months(MAX_DATE,-23)

Can anyone suggest me something ?

Comment: add your some queries...

Comment: select ....... from 
(SELECT MAX(data_mo_dt) AS MAX_DATE FROM M_FRMLRY_PLAN_DRUG_RSTRCTN_TEMP) B
inner join
M_FRMLRY_PLAN_DRUG_RSTRCTN_TEMP A
on 1=1
WHERE  a.data_mo_dt >= Add_months(MAX_DATE,-23)

Comment: It seems that by using on 1=1 you're trying to produce the Cartesian join of a large table with itself. Was that your intention ?